# Every finite abelian extension of Q contains a totally real subfield of index 2?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I can reduce this to the case of cyclotomic field extensions, by embedding the abelian extension into a cyclotomic extension and using the "sliding-up" lemma.

I am stuck on how to prove this for the cyclotomic case.

I saw this on wikipedia and was intruiged.

Comment: Are you sure it's not **index** 2? Then you could just take the fixed subfield of complex conjugation.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this? Where in wikipedia did you see this statement?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_real_number_field - but looking at it again I see that there is an exception in the case that the extension is itself totally real.

Comment: The statement from Wikipedia says "An abelian extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ is either totally real, or contains a totally real subfield **over which** it has degree two." This means that the totally real subfield is index 2, not degree 2, as @Zev mentioned. This is otherwise false as stated; for example, the compositum of a cyclic cubic extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ and an imaginary quadratic field will not satisfy the incorrect condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Q(w + w^{-1})$ is quadratic and totally real, the latter because complex conjugation is in the abelian galois group (and hence commutes with any of the galois elements), and the former because if $k = w + w^{-1}$, then $x^2 - kx + 1$ is a quadratic minimal polynomial for w over Q(k).

Comment: Sorry, it should be a minimal polynomial for w, not k. Also there was a typo.